# Move documents from one folder to another in diferent library in different site collection from Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, asp.net

I want find and move all documents from one folder to other in different site collection document library. Both the folders are at the sub folder level 3 from the actual list. Please let me know how can I achieve this from client object model.

Folder structure are same in both libraries except the name of root folder

> Library A
>
> ->Sub Folder 1
>   ->Sub Folder 2
>   ->Source Folder (Move the documents from this folder)static folder
>
> Library B
>
> ->Sub Folder 1
>   ->Sub Folder 2
>   ->Destination Folder (Move the documents to this folder)name different

```
   // set up the src client
    ClientContext srcContext = new ClientContext(srcUrl);

    // set up the destination context
    ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);

    // get the source list and items
    Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
    List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Components");

    ListItemCollection itemColl = srcList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
    srcContext.Load(itemColl);
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    ListItemCreationInformation info = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    info.FolderUrl = string.Format("{0}/list/{1}/{2}", srcUrl, srcLibrary, "/articlepages/Kishantest/");
    var listitem = srcList.AddItem(info);
    listitem.Update();
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

    srcContext.Load(itemColl);
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

  // get the destination list
   Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
   destContext.Load(destWeb);
   destContext.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (var doc in itemColl)
       {
           try
           {

     File file = doc.File;
     srcContext.Load(file);
     srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

     // build destination url
     string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + file.Name;
    // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
    FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
    File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
    srcContext.Load(file);
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
    }
       }
```

Calling Function

```
CopyDocuments("sitecolletionurl" + ddlsourcelocation.SelectedValue.ToString(), "/Components/articlepages/Kishantest", "sitecolletionurl" + ddllangauge.SelectedValue.ToString(), "Components/articlepages" + "/" + txtarticlename.Text.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

//Read Source file into byte array

```
FileInformation srcfile =  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(src_clientContext,file.ServerRelativeUrl);
byte[] bytesarr = ReadStream(srcfile.Stream);

public byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

// destination library creates file from byte array of source file

```
var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
fileCreationInformation.Content = bytesarr;
fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
fileCreationInformation.Url = "URL to Upload";

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = List.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
dest_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

// After file added to destination library you can delete it from source library if want